# Wicket: highte all the rows in a dataview

Tags: java, wicket

I implemented the function of highlite [here](https://examples8x.wicket.apache.org/repeater/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.repeater.OIRPage?0)

It work fine, but now I need to highlite all the rows.
I did that:

```
    private void seleccionarTodos(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        Iterator<Component> it = datosListView.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            HighlitableDataItem<Historial> item = (HighlitableDataItem<Historial> )it.next();
            if(!item.highlite){
                item.toggleHighlite();
                target.add(item);
            }
        }
        inicializarSelected(true);

        container.add(datosListView);
        target.add(form);

    }
```

It doesn't throw any errors but no highlite any row, if there was some, they came swich off.
I though that mayby this actions can't be actioned from a button event, but i put the same code in the action of the event that hilight one row and it doesnt work. Some one has implemented the functionality of highlite all the rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. The mistake was add:

```
 container.add(datosListView);
 target.add(form);
```

Should add only the item!